# How can i solve this error "System.ServiceModel.FaultException"

Tags: c#, acumatica

Everytime I stop the program and rerun again the error message pop

> PX.Data.PXException: API Login Limit
>      at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.Post(ISoapSystemContract systemContract, XmlReader requestReader, String serviceNamespace, String internalNamespace, MethodInfo method, Func`1 serviceFactory, IEdmModel edmModel)
>      at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Login>d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()

this is my code on log in

```
...
using (DefaultSoapClient soapClient = new DefaultSoapClient())
{
       //Log in to Acumatica ERP        
       soapClient.Login
       (
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserName,
            Properties.Settings.Default.Password,
            Properties.Settings.Default.CompanyName,
            Properties.Settings.Default.Branch,
            null
       );
 ...
      try
      {
           ...
           soapClient.Logout();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           ...
           soapClient.Logout();
      }
      finally
      {
           ...
      }
```

what's wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

Comment: get rid of the the `soapClient` using statement and see if that helps - using statements can play games with api clients...

Comment: Which part is throwing the exception?  Is it on `client.Logout()` or during the dispose of the `using` statement?

Comment: @fourwhey at the soapClient.Login

Comment: What is the message of the Excepiton?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya look at quoted part

Comment: On which code line do you get the exception?

Comment: @Qwerty that's *not* the message. That's only part of it. The rest will contain what's actually happened. Post the *full* exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`. Don't bother with the `using` clause, it's *doesn't* affect anything when everything goes OK

Comment: @Qwerty a `FaultException` means the *other service* returned an error message. The FaultException *contains* that error object and full message. If that's thrown by `Login()` it probably means that login failed. You can't "fix" anything without knowing what the actual problem was, so you *have* to check what the [exception's properties and FaultMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) are.

Comment: @johnB `using` doesn't affect how proxies work. It only affects how they are *closed*. If everything goes OK they cause no problems. It's only in the case of exceptions that a proxy needs special handling to close

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the message was too long wait I will edit

Answer (score 2):

Unlicensed demo versions have a limited amount of API connection session available.

You have to make sure Logout is *always* called after Login otherwise you'll run out of available connection sessions. For unlicensed version you should aim for a maximum of 1 connection at any time and make sure the application can't be stopped without executing the API connection session logout.

Here's the stategy I would use to ensure that:

- Use only single threaded code to interact with the API because you
  want to avoid multiple concurrent connections when using unlicensed
  version.
- Wrap all code interacting with the API in exception block that will
  always call logout. It doesn't hurt to be paranoid here, you can event put the login code in the try block because if login fails there's no harm in trying to logout.
- Try to make your session short and to the point, don't login
  pre-emptively or keep the connection opened for longer than required.
  Having sessions hanging around for too long increases the chances of
  losing the connection before you can issue the logout command or
  simply forgetting to logout.
- Register an application wide OnClose event handler to Logout of the
  session when the user soft closes the application. If the user hard closes the application (ex: by killing it with task manager) you can't execute logout so you'll have to wait for the session to expire or restart IIS to avoid API connection limit exceeded errors.
- Log each connection login/logout attempts to disk (whether successful
  or not) to make sure it always calls logout for each login. When
  login is executed create a unique id for that connection and log it,
  when logout is executed log it with the same unique id. If you get
  the API limit error again you'll have log data to confirm whether or
  not you have successfully logout of all opened sessions.

Comment: Can you clear the logins somehow? I'm working against a demo version for development work, so kicking any logins is ok.

Comment: yes, open admin command prompt and run IISReset or go to page Apply Updates and click on RESTART APPLICATION or open inetmgr and restart the website.